# Xamarin IOS Button ID where to find

Tags: ios, button, xamarin

I need some help on find the button in ViewController. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gja3W.png)

As you can see in the image the Hello World is the default button in the screen. However, I cannot understand how did the code connect to that button.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlUFn.png)
As I tried to click on that Button, it does not show any related have name or identity. May I know how or where is the Button linked or called?

Comment: Add first: Don't provide your code as an image. Please copy and past it here. Second: There is a ViewController.designer.cs file next to your ViewController.cs file. Because it is a UI control placed inside a storyboard Xamarin will automatically reference it for you. This reference is made inside the *.designer.cs file.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/introduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Click the Button on your storyboard, Open the Properties View (View > Pads > Properties). Give the button a name. That's it, Xamarin studio will create the required outlets.

Now if you open the `ViewController.designer.cs` file. You can see outlets are created. You'll find the below code in your `ViewController.designer.cs`

```
[Outlet]
UIKit.UIButton Button { get; set; }

void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
{
    if (Button != null) {
        Button.Dispose ();
        Button = null;
    }
}
```